# Set minimum days difference between jquery ui datepickers

Tags: jquery-ui-datepicker

I have two date pickers that I use to select a date range. Here is the code for them:

```
$("#ContentPlaceHolder1_MySearchBox_txtOutDate").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    dateFormat: 'dd-M-yy',
    onClose: function (selectedDate) {
      $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_MySearchBox_txtInDate").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
      DoPostBack();
    },
    beforeShow: function () {
      setTimeout(function () {
        $('.ui-datepicker').css('z-index', 99999999999999);
      }, 0);
    }
  }).val();
  $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_MySearchBox_txtInDate").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    dateFormat: 'dd-M-yy',
    onClose: function (selectedDate) {
      $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_MySearchBox_txtOutDate").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
      DoPostBack();
    },
    beforeShow: function () {
      setTimeout(function () {
        $('.ui-datepicker').css('z-index', 99999999999999);
      }, 0);
    }
  }).val();
```

The code works fine when it comes to not allowing the InDate from being lower than the OutDate. But I need to set the minimum value for InDate to be at least 3 days after the OutDate. I tried using `New Date(selectedDate)` to add 3 days but it didn't work because "selectedDate" is a string of dd-MMM-YYYY format and it won't convert to date.

What is the simplest method to achieve what I am after?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

OK. I found a solution using the following functions:

```
    function parseDate(input) {
  var parts = input.split('-');
  return new Date(parts[2], MonthNameToNumber(parts[1]) - 1, parts[0]);
}

function MonthNameToNumber(MonthName) { 
  switch(MonthName) {
      case "Jan":
        return 1;
        break;
      case "Feb":
        return 2;
        break;
      case "Mar":
        return 3;
        break;
      case "Apr":
        return 4;
        break;
      case "May":
        return 5;
        break;
      case "Jun":
        return 6;
        break;
      case "Jul":
        return 7;
        break;
      case "Aug":
        return 8;
        break;
      case "Sep":
        return 9;
        break;
      case "Oct":
        return 10;
        break;
      case "Nov":
        return 11;
        break;
      case "Dec":
        return 12;
        break;
      default:
        return 1;
  }
}
```

And then changing:

`$("#ContentPlaceHolder1_MySearchBox_txtInDate").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);`

to

```
          var OutDate = parseDate(selectedDate);
      OutDate.setDate(OutDate.getDate() + 3);
      $("#<%=txtInDate.ClientID%>").datepicker("option", "minDate", OutDate);
```

and

`$("#ContentPlaceHolder1_MySearchBox_txtOutDate").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);`

to

```
          var InDate = parseDate(selectedDate);
      InDate.setDate(InDate.getDate() - 3);
      $("#<%=txtOutDate.ClientID%>").datepicker("option", "maxDate", InDate);
```